# Как выбрать все HTML-элементы внутри .info, кроме strong?

Tags: html, css

```
    <li>
        <p class="info">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. <span>Illo</span> sunt eveniet maxime quasi harum, tenetur corporis fugit ullam dicta, magnam molestias? <strong>Tenetur</strong> tempora animi laudantium excepturi perferendis esse id molestiae impedit odio aliquam rem totam optio, magni illo! <span>Dicta</span> dolore aperiam voluptates impedit necessitatibus nemo fugit incidunt hic! Ex, incidunt repudiandae. <span>Error</span> ipsam possimus consectetur quo maxime esse ullam delectus tenetur harum, voluptate explicabo adipisci enim in sed officia expedita natus cumque ut. Repellat eveniet nemo <strong>laboriosam</strong> tenetur neque nam cupiditate recusandae et, esse, nobis eum animi, consequuntur impedit vel tempore? <span>Porro</span> facere explicabo labore autem. Facilis eius perspiciatis quod?
        </p>
    </li>
```

Пробую `.info:not(strong)`, ничего не получается

Comment: `.info :not(strong)` пробел пропустили.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пробелы могут быть значимыми в css селекторах.

```
.info:not(strong)
```

Данный селектор выбирает все элементы с классом `.info` - которые при этом **НЕ** тег `strong`

Если нужно искать внутри `.info`, не зависимо от уровня вложенности, достаточно добавить пробел:

```
.info :not(strong)
```

Данный селектор выбирает все элементы, которые при этом **НЕ** тег `strong`, внутри элемента с классом `.info`.

Если нужно выбрать непосредственных детей, можно воспользоваться `>`

```
.info > :not(strong)
```